# Hibernate: How to make entity and all associations readOnly by default? (or auto-evict the association from the session)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity which belongs to a customer entity.
I would like the entity **including** all associations to be kind of read-only.

```
public class Foo{

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    // getters for both fields ....

}
```

Here is what I want:

1. Calls to setters of foo should not be persisted.
2. Calls to myFoo.getCustomer() should return a readonly customer so that calls to setters like myFoo.getCustomer().setSomething("should not be persisted") should not work.

Example:

```
List<Foo> list = fooDAO.getList();
for (Foo foo : liust) {
  String f1 = foo.getCustomer().getSomeField(); // should work
  foo.getCustomer.setSomeField("change that should not be persisted"); // calling this setter should not have an effect or should even throw an UnsupportedOperationException() or something

  foo.setFirstName("change should not be persisted"); // also this should not be persisted.
}
```

Currently my solution for the association is kind of manual:

```
public Customers getCustomer() {
    // detach the referenced object from the Hibernate session
    // to avoid that changes to these association are persisted to the database
    getCustomersDAO().evict(customer); // calls session.evict(o) under the hood
    return customer;
}
```

Here is my question:
What ways are there to avoid changes to associations being persisted to the Database? E.g. using an annotation?

In general I would like this behaviour to be the default. 
But it should also be possible to allow changes to be persisted. So I need it configurable. So I though about doing it on the Query-level.

**My environment:**

- Hibernate v3.6
- Spring 3.2 with HibernateDAOSupport /
  HibernateTemplate and annotation based Transaction-handling.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue.  I was storing filename as a property of an object in the database, and then trying to manipulate it in the application after reading it to reflect storage path based on environment.  I tried making the DAO transaction readOnly, and hibernate still persisted changes of the property to the db.  I then used entityManager.detach(object) before I manipulated the property, and that worked.  But, I then later got tangled up into issues where other service methods that were dependent the auto persistence of objects to the db weren't behaving as they should.

The lesson I learned is that if you need to manipulate a property of a object that you don't want persisted, then make a "transient" property for that object with it's own getters and setters, and make sure the transient property setter isn't passed properties from the entity model that then become manipulated.  For example, if you have a property "filename" of String, and you have a transient property of "s3key", the first thing the "s3Key" property setter should do is make a new String object passed into the setter for it to use in the manipulation.

```
@Transient
private String s3Key;

public String getS3Key {
   String s3key = s3Prefix + "/" + <other path info> + this.filename;
   return s3key;
}
```

Though all the "readOnly" and "detach" stuff for jpa/hibernate allows for custom handling of persistence of objects to the db, it just seems going to that length to customize the behavior of the objects to that extent causes supportability problems later, when persisting entity changes automatically is expected or counted on in other service functions.  My own experience has been it is best to use a programming pattern of making use of transient properties for handling changes to entities you don't want persisted.